# Should I not update the plugin?

Tags: plugins

I am currently trying to build a website for a client using WordPress for a school project. The client requires a user system with a log in and storage of user permissions and information.I downloaded a plugin called Simple Membership because it had the best reviews for user membership plugins.

The biggest problem I am experiencing at the moment is the default contact information that comes with the plugin is not the information I wish to store. I need other fields to be stored. I am a developer so I first took a look at the code using FTP and made a few changes just to the registration form to show off to the client for the first iteration.

I have now been made aware that when updating the plugin all of my changes will be overridden. I am here to ask what would happen if I decided to make changes directly to the files and just not update the plugin. The website doesn't need to be secure. The only information being stored is names and some personal information. No credit card numbers or anything of that nature that needs to be protected. Will my site crash if I don't update my plugin?

Comment: https://simple-membership-plugin.com/simple-membership-documentation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several points which should be clear when starting such a project.

- WordPress is constantly updating, think about extra layer protection
  through updates or changes in the GUI. (meaning by that, updating
  core files)
- A plugin relies on Wordpress core, which need to be updated also when
  there are changes which can cause conflicts. In worse case it holds
  the plugin from working if not to block WordPress completely from
  working caused by code which caused a major conflict.
- Never ever change corefiles from either WordPress itself or a Plugin.
  The reasons are obvious and speaking for itself.
- You can/should write own code when changes are needed for WordPress or
  a plugin. Create a plugin or add it to `functions.php` in the theme.
  There are often options to ask a developer if it is possible to help
  you with problems and the community can also help you out.

> The website doesn't need to be secure.
>
> > The only information being stored is names and some personal information.

Ehm sorry but, names and some personal information, no need to be secure?

- What about students who are eager enough to invest time to see how secure the school systems are and what more.
- What about the connection with the Internet (if one exist), no need to secure because nothing will/can happen?

Maybe you think again when mentioning such en public in a society anno 2016 and you want/need clients for living. *(yes sorry maybe synical/harsh but hey, that is how I think about such)*

So in the bottom line, the answer for the question as it:
*Should I not update the plugin*

You should always update a plugin when changes are important enough to keep all running as wished. 
Yes, sometimes you can skip an update if the changes are not major enough (for the plugin itself or Wordpress) in personal cases.
But hey the 'only' thing that can happen when not updating is that a client will start complaining because WordPress and/or plugins are not working as expected, in worse case it does nothing anymore.

This is just my personal opinion and maybe others have a totally other view and agree with your way of handling it.

Cheers.

Comment: I am not being paid and the client is getting the site for free. It is sponsored by our school and odds are the site will never go live with production data so do not think this is an option I would consider in a real world situation however it is obvious making the site updatable is a must.

Comment: @bdevinedev , Lets say, that idea was a really great example of a horrible idea.